Pinescript - Premarket high low query
I would like to query the highest and lowest price from the premarket session and draw a line at these two prices.
I tried this:
if session.ispremarket 
    pmHigh := high
    pmLow := low

x1 = line.new(bar_index, pmHigh, bar_index + 1, pmHigh, color = #e21717e6, width = 2)
x2 = line.new(bar_index, pmLow, bar_index + 1, pmLow, color = #0ceb1fe6, width = 2)


Unfortunately the line is not displayed correctly.
Or several lines are displayed
